# Is there any way to select records if top clause parameter is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to select records if top clause parameter is null?

```
DECLARE @count FLOAT = 0;

Select @count = count from tblDetails

SELECT TOP(@count) from tblCompany
```

If @count var is null than i want to select all records from tblCompany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @count FLOAT = 0;

Select @count = count(1) from tblDetails

IF @count > 0
BEGIN
SELECT TOP(@intRecords) * from tblCompany
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tblCompany
END
```

If you do not want to write the query twice - although only one will get executed, you can try this:

```
    DECLARE @count FLOAT = 0;

    Select @count = count(1) from tblDetails

    IF @count = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @intRecords = 100000 -- Or some number larger than the possible count
    END
    SELECT TOP(@intRecords) * from tblCompany
```

Comment: I really don't want to write query twice.

Comment: Any solution to do that with single query?

Answer (score 1):

When facing situations like this one, I love using SQL [Rank](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx).

In the query below I assumed you have an `ID` column, but you can replace it with any other column for choosing the criteria for what would be considered to be the top columns:

```
DECLARE @count FLOAT = 0;
Select @count = count(*) from tblDetails

SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT      
    RANK () OVER 
    ( ORDER BY ID ) 'Rank', -- <-- Assuming you have an ID column, replace with any other criteria for what will be considered as top...
    *
FROM tblCompany
) tmp
WHERE (@count IS NULL) OR tmp.Rank <= @count
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
DECLARE @count AS INT ;

Set @count = (Select count(*) from tblDetails);

SELECT TOP(ISNULL(@count,5)) * from tblCompany
```